# Unplugged Ethernet Cable Causing Network Slowdown

Tags: networking, performance, ethernet, hub

A few days ago the internet speed on my main PC went to near zero. It's an HP Elite with Win 7. Here's the setup:

NIC - 2' ethernet cable - union - 10' eth cable - union - 25' eth cable - powered eth hub - amplifi router - Arris surfeboard modem

I started by rebooting the PC - no change. Then I started removing all those crazy links in the cable so that I was just plugged into the 25' eth cable - no change. All the wireless devices are getting 15-20 Mbs and the one other hard wired PC is getting 80 Mbs. I rebooted everything - no change. I tried different ports on the hub and the modem - no change.

I turned off wireless on my laptop and plugged it into the 25' cable - same poor performance as the desktop. So it must be the cable. I take the laptop down to the ethernet hub and plug it in with the 2' cable and get < .1 Mbs. So it must be the hub.

As I'm identifying all the things plugged into the hub, I notice that there is a cable plugged into the first port that isn't plugged in on the other end. I remove that cable from the hub and I get 80 Mbs on the laptop. I plug the desktop back into the hub using the 25' cable and get 18 Mbs.

My question, at long last, is: How could a cable plugged into a hub that's not plugged in on the other end affect network performance? And why all of a sudden?

Also, I'm going to replace that 25' cable because I think it's responsible for the difference in performance between the laptop and the desktop. It's the first ethernet cable I ever made and I was terrible and putting ends on cables (and still am).

Comment: What's the model of the "hub" (which I suspect is really a switch)?

Comment: Correct, it's a switch. TP-Link 5 port TL-SG105

Comment: It shouldn't. I could see it cause a potential problem in that situation if it were a bad cable and had some sort of short in it though.